# Visual Studio project PublishProfiles location

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

PublishProfiles for Visual Studio project (*.pubxml files) are stored in Properties\PublishProfiles\ subfolder.

Is it possible to change default location of those files to some other like Settings\PublishProfiles and have Publish prompt read them properly?